# Symfony - Use underscore or dot instead of brackets with FormType in URL query (get method)

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.3

I search to use *underscore* or *dot* instead of *brackets* with FormType in URL query with GET method.

### Current

I've actually this URL when I submit my form:

```
/path?fieldName%5BsubFieldName%5D=toto
```

Or this (decoded):

```
/path?fieldName[subFieldName]=toto
```

### Expected

I'd like to have this:

```
/path?fieldName_subFieldName=toto
```

Or this:

```
/path?fieldName.subFieldName=toto
```

### Tried

I tried a few options in the form configuration but I don't know what they correspond to, and I don't know where to google (what terms to use).

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal behaviour of Symfony Form Component.
To avoid this, you should use named form builder, like this :

```php
public function controllerMethod(FormFactory $formFactory) {
    $form = $formFactory->createNamed(
        '',                 // Your form name
        MyFormType::class, // Your form type
        [],               // data
        []               // form options
    );

    // Do something
}
```

For the button, you have to remove it from your `Form` class (i mean, the `SubmitType` one), and add it manually tou your html (with classical `<button></button>` inside of your form rendering)